# Need to have SSIS package which can generate CSV file for any dynamically given query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a requirement to design an SSIS package where I need to pick up SQL query from a text file (remember, the query can change) and generate a CSV file for queries data output.
for example, on the first day I can have a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

and the next day it can change to :

```
SELECT * FROM Department
```

so, any pointers to generate such an SSIS package would help.

Comment: This isn't a question. SSIS is built to deal with defined data sets, it's not set up like "Here's a query, export it please.". You would be better off using `bcp` for this.

Comment: You can check here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b3c4738-a4e5-44bc-a5c9-78d21bf974d4/using-dynamic-query-in-ssis-and-mapping-it-to-flat-file-destination?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try?